# Switching between two forms in same window

Tags: c#, winforms, forms

I have 3 forms:

1. Login Form
2. Register Form
3. Main Form

The Program starts with `Application.Run(new FormLogin());`

The User can register. For that I use something like (*buttonRegister* is Pressed)

```
        this.Hide();

        FormRegister registerForm = new FormRegister();
        registerForm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual;
        registerForm.Location = this.Location;

        if (registerForm.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            // Save the information from the Registration and register
        }
        else
        {
            this.Show();
        }
        this.Location = registerForm.Location;
```

Then the user logs in (with or without registration) I start the `Main Form` by (*buttonLogin is pressed*)

```
            this.Hide();
            FormMain f = new FormMain(this); // give information needed
            f.Show();
```

**Question:** is there a better way to switch between the Login and Registration Frames, so that no new window has to open up(it takes time) and so that the window keeps its position?

Comment: Put a using block around your registerform

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having 2 separate forms, consider putting your existing forms into 2 different Panel controls and hiding/showing the panels as needed.